# Send an email using gitbash - Command not found

Tags: shell, git-bash

I have a file.sh which i am trying to incorporate an email. I keep getting the following : mail command not found or mailx command not found

```
echo "hello" | sendmail -f send@email.com -t destination@email.com
```

Also tried the following :

```
https://www.codexpedia.com/shell/send-email-from-shell-command-line/
```

But it doesnt work
Any reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, by git-bash, you means [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) bash session, that is not surprising.

Try instead to use the [`git send-email` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email) which can send a file content as an email.